# Django Settings variable *sometimes* getting reset and unsure why

Tags: python, django

I have a dict defined in my Django `settings.py` to act as a sort of...fake, temporary cache of data for all of my users. However, it has come to my attention that it is not behaving the way I would like and is resetting back to it's default value seemingly at random.

`settings.py`

```
# initialize with a fake key:value for ease in logging
STORE_DATA = {'hello': 'goodbye'}
```

`views.py`

```
def get_data(name):
        from apiclient.discovery import build

        search_q = name
        service = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey='<key-here>')
        results = service.search().list(
            part='snippet', 
            channelId='<channel-here>',
            type='video',
            q=search_q,
        ).execute()

        settings.STORE_DATA[name] = results['items']
        result = settings.STORE_DATA[name]
        return result

    page.videos = []
    if page.name in settings.STORE_DATA:
        page.videos = settings.STORE_DATA[page.name]
    else:
        page.videos = get_data(page.name)
```

This is the only code that references this global variable. It's just simply storing the results of a youtube api call so we don't have to make a query every time someone visits the page.

However - sometimes this works, sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes the key:value pairs stored in the dict get reset back to it's initial state. Here is a little print out from my log -

```
cache before the call - [u'hello']
"page1" - 2018-08-22 23:23:47
cache after the call - [u'page1', u'hello']

cache before the call - [u'hello']
"page1" - 2018-08-22 23:24:13
cache after the call - [u'page1', u'hello']

cache before the call - [u'page1', u'hello']
page1 - found in cache!
cache after the call - [u'page1', u'hello']

cache before the call - [u'page1', u'hello']
page1 - found in cache!
cache after the call - [u'page1', u'hello']

cache before the call - [u'hello']
"page1" - 2018-08-22 23:27:50
cache after the call - [u'page1', u'hello']
```

You can see the first time, it properly does not have the data in the cache, so it stores it. Good. The second time...wait. The data isn't there. Stores it again. Third time and fourth time - it's there! Nice! Fifth time - wtf. Gone again.

This is super weird and doesn't make any sense to me. Anyone have an idea of what could be happening?

Comment: Are you using the development server or a production system such as uwsgi? You should generally use a production ready caching system, such as `memcached` by the way.

Comment: @Selcuk Yeah this is on our test server that is deployed with nginx and uwsgi. We are using memcached as well but, at the moment, this system is separate.

Comment: @Selcuk I think that's what it was. Per your recommendation, I moved it over to our memcached instead and it's working much better. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple workers configured for `uwsgi` they each will have their own Python interpreter (and each worker will have a separate copy of your dictionary). That's why it is recommended to use a single data store for caching purposes.

You can test this by setting the `workers` (or `processors`, they are synonyms) setting to `1` to see if that resolves the issue.